# Performing automatic segue using PFUser.currentUser() on app launch

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, segue

I have an app that is using Parse to grab the locally stored currently logged in user for my app. When I launch the app from the home screen I want to avoid forcing my users to login everytime so I grab the currently logged in user using PFUser.currentuser() like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        if PFUser.currentUser()?.username != nil {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoggedIn", sender: self)

        }

}
```

I then just want to perform a segue to a "dashboard" if that user has already logged in. the code

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoggedIn", sender: self)
```

works beautifully everywhere else in my code. However, when I try to use it in ViewDidLoad() is when it is giving me trouble. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to perform the code snippet in my question in the ViewDidAppear() func like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    println(PFUser.currentUser())

    if PFUser.currentUser()?.username != nil {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoggedIn", sender: self)

    }

}
```